# My Facebook app installs the wrong (old) tab image

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

My Facebook app installs the wrong (old) tab image, even though I've changed the page tab image in my app settings. This is an app we used last summer now being repurposed for this year.

Here's the code we're using to install: http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=114231258660944&redirect_uri=http://viewer.zmags.com/services/addToFacebookPage

Any ideas? Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the way your custom apps appear on your page by going to “Manage” from the admin panel and choose “Edit Page” in the drop-down menu. Under the “Apps” section, click “Edit Settings” for the specific app image (111 x 74 pixels) you’d like to adjust.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Turns out I had done everything correctly and it was something wonky happening with my particular Facebook account. When anyone else went through the app/tab installation process, it worked perfectly. Mine may have been caching the old/wrong image.